# firebase filter by timestamp

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I have a document in a firestore collection, one field is timestamp
How can I filter this field?
If this were a integer I could do this

```
.where('time', '>', moment().unix())
```

but in this format what can I do?

[image: timestamp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Google Support says

```
const startOfDay = new Date();
startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection('posts').where('createdAt', '>=', startOfDay)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, " -> ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

So, I must use javascript date object